# MySQL subquery in select, return multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I am working with 2 tables. `location` and `us_zipcodes`.

`location` contains user coordinates and travel speed.

`us_zipcodes` contains all cities, their zipcodes, and coordinates in the US.

The goal here is to return the users latitude, longitude, speed, and nearest city.

In my select, I am trying to return 2 columns from `us_zipcodes` in a select subquery. I understand one might recommend a join, but my circumstances do not allow an `ON`.

The subquery selects the city based on the users coordinates that are closest to the city's coordinates in the `us_zipcodes` table.

I am looking to know if what I want to do is possible, and if so, the correct syntax.

My attempt is below. Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT
    l.lat,
    l.lng,
    l.speed
    (
        SELECT
            CONCAT(city, ' ', state_abrv) AS nearest, 
            (
                3959 * 
                acos( 
                    cos( radians( l.lat ) ) * 
                    cos( radians( lat ) ) * 
                    cos( 
                        radians( lng ) - 
                        radians( l.lng ) 
                    ) + 
                    sin( radians( l.lat ) ) * 
                    sin( radians( lat ) ) 
                ) 
            ) AS distance
        FROM
            us_zipcodes
        ORDER BY
            distance ASC
        LIMIT 0, 1
    ) AS nearest, distance
FROM
    location AS l
WHERE
    l.userID = :userID
```

EDIT: My table structure is as shown.

TABLE: `location`

```
ID      |       lat         |       lng         |       speed       |       userID  
___________________________________________________________________________________
1       |       55.159399   |       -74.98976   |       35          |       1       
2       |       45.168399   |       -52.56476   |       45          |       2       
3       |       64.593399   |       -64.32576   |       55          |       3       
4       |       98.193399   |       -72.81176   |       65          |       4
```

TABLE: `us_zipcodes`

```
ID      |       city        |       state_abrv      |       lat     |       lng
______________________________________________________________________________________
1       |       Foo City    |       MI              |       45.3265 |       -81.98747
2       |       Bar City    |       AK              |       65.3265 |       -65.98747
3       |       Fake City   |       FL              |       25.3265 |       -75.98747
4       |       Smith City  |       MI              |       64.3265 |       -89.98747
```

Comment: could you provide your table structure

Comment: *my circumstances do not allow an `ON`.*  Why not?

Comment: Because there is no sharing columns in the two tables. There is no link. The selection in the inner join is based on the nearest coordinates compared to the lat and lng of the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this can help

```
SELECT
  state_abrv,
  city,
  3959 * acos(
      cos( radians( (SELECT lat FROM location WHERE userID = :userID) ) ) *
      cos( radians( lat ) ) *
      cos(
          radians( lng ) -
          radians( (SELECT lng FROM location WHERE userID = :userID) )
      ) +
      sin( radians( (SELECT lat FROM location WHERE userID = :userID) )) *
      sin( radians( lat ) )
  ) AS distanse,
  (SELECT lng FROM location WHERE userID = :userID) as lng,
  (SELECT lat FROM location WHERE userID = :userID) as lat,
  (SELECT speed FROM location WHERE userID = :userID) as speed

FROM us_zipcodes ORDER BY distanse LIMIT 1;
```

or just two separate subqueries

```
SELECT
  l.lat,
  l.lng,
  l.speed,
  (SELECT (3959 * acos(
                cos(radians(l.lat)) *
                cos(radians(lat)) *
                cos(radians(lng)-radians(l.lng)) +
                sin(radians(l.lat)) *
                sin(radians(lat)))
  ) 
   FROM us_zipcodes
   ORDER BY distance ASC
   LIMIT 0, 1
  ) AS distance,
  (SELECT CONCAT(city, ' ', state_abrv)
   FROM us_zipcodes
   WHERE 3959 *
         acos(cos(radians(l.lat)) * cos(radians(lat)) *
             cos( radians(lng) - radians(l.lng)) +
             sin(radians(l.lat)) *
             sin(radians(lat))
         ) = distance)  AS nearest
FROM
  location AS l
WHERE
  l.userID = :userID;
```